# Editing Database field type using db:migrate

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-3, dbmigrate

I am working on a Ruby on Rails web application and I am interested in changing the type of two of the fields in my `Project` model. When I created the Model I gave two of my fields (`start_time` and `end_time`) the type int and I would like to change it to a  date/time type.

Since I am working with a team (and probably also because it is right to do it this way) I would like to change these field types using `rake db:migrate`. How would i create a file to do this? What are the best (or only) date/time types existing in Ruby/Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `script/rails generate migration UpdateTimeFields` and use the following. (There is also a `change_column` method, but I don't believe it's capable of changing an int column to a datetime column while still preserving any data).

```
class UpdateTimeFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :projects, :start_time, :old_start_time
    rename_column :projects, :end_time, :old_end_time
    add_column :projects, :start_time, :datetime
    add_column :projects, :end_time, :datetime

    # If applicable, insert code to iterate through your existing
    # records and update the new start_time and end_time fields
    # based on your int data.

    remove_column :projects, :old_start_time
    remove_column :projects, :old_end_time
  end

  def self.down
    # do the opposite of above: rename the datetime fields, create the int
    # fields again, migrate the data back into the int fields, and delete
    # the datetime fields.
  end
end
```

Comment: Do i get any extra 'features' using datetime, like a datetime picker or at least error messages for wrong format?

Comment: When it's a datetime field, you can do proper validations, easily query the database for specific time ranges, etc. For a datetime picker, that's a UI element in the view which is not directly related to the database fields. However, most date pickers will submit data which is compatible with a datetime field.